# dictionaries in python: summing the values returned from searching the keys

Tags: python, dictionary, sum

I am just learning Python so this is probably very simple. I am trying to find the values that match the keys in a dictionary and add them up. I have written the code which finds the values and I can print it ( tested this out in Online Python Tutor to see what happens) But I can't figure out how to just get this as a total score which returns the correct score (6). I know this is not a function at the moment.

```
    SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES = {
        'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 3, 'd': 2, 'e': 1, 'f': 4, 'g': 2, 'h': 4, 'i': 1, 'j': 8, 'k': 5, 'l': 1, 'm': 3, 'n': 1, 'o': 1, 'p': 3, 'q': 10, 'r': 1, 's': 1, 't': 1, 'u': 1, 'v': 4, 'w': 4, 'x': 8, 'y': 4, 'z': 10
    }
word ='tact'
score =0

for i in range(len(word)):
    for letter,score in SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES.items():
        if letter == word[i]:
            print score
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I would use this piece of code:

```
score = 0
word = 'tact'
for letter in word:
    score += SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES[letter]
print score
```

There are more effective ways too, for example the one mentioned by NPE, but if you're just a beginner, I would prefer using (and understanding) this method.

---

**What the above code does, line by line:**

1) First we use a `for`-loop to iterate over each letter in your `word`:

```
for letter in word:
```

2) For each letter we increment `score` variable by the corresponding amount you've defined in `SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES` like so:

```
score = score + SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES[letter]
```

This can be written easier with `+=`:

```
score += SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES[letter]
```

3) Finally we print the score:

```
print score
```

Comment: Why the downvotes? I wouldn't teach Python to a beginner by teaching `sum()` and list comprehension first.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response and explanation- it is really helpful

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> sum(SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES[l] for l in word)
6
```

Here:

1. `for l in word` iterates over the letters of `word`;
2. `SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES[l]` gets the corresponding entries of `SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES`;
3. `sum(...)` adds them up.

The construct inside `sum()` is called a [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/).

Comment: OP is just learning, so it is worth nothing that this is map and reduce. The expression SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES[l] for l in word is a mapping function and sum is a reduce function.

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick response and the explanation- I have searched everywhere for a simple answer.